# Trouble Using push_back in Class

Tags: c++

I am having a problem using the 'push_back' vector function for my class 'room'.  I am trying to push back values into the private vector variables in the 'room' class.  I think my problem is just a misunderstanding of how the 'push_back' function works, but I do not know what I am doing wrong in enough detail to rectify the problem myself.

This is the problem area:

```
void room::assign_exit_index(int index) {
  exit_index.push_back(index);
}

void room::assign_exit_direction(string direction) {
  exit_direction.push_back(direction);
}

void room::assign_exit_locked(bool exit_locked) {
  exit_locked.push_back(exit_locked);
}

void room::assign_gold(Money gold) {
  gold.push_back(gold);
}

void room::assign_key(Key key) {
  key.push_back(key);
}

void room::assign_potion(int potion) {
  potion.push_back(potion);
}

void room::assign_have_weapon(bool have_weapon) {
  have_weapon.push_back(have_weapon);
}

void room::assign_weapon_index(int weapon_index) {
  weapon_index.push_back(weapon_index);
}

void room::assign_have_scroll(bool have_scroll) {
  have_scroll.push_back(have_scroll);
}

void room::assign_scroll_index(int scroll_index) {
  scroll_index.push_back(scroll_index);
}

void room::assign_have_monster(bool have_monster) {
  have_monster.push_back(have_monster);
}

void room::assign_monster_index(int monster_index){
  monster_index.push_back(monster_index);
}
```

This is the 'room' class declaration:

```
class room{

 public:

  room();

  friend void generate_rooms (ifstream& input_file, vector<room>& rooms_f);

  void assign_exit_index(int index);
  void assign_exit_direction(string direction);
  void assign_exit_locked(bool exit_locked);
  void assign_gold(Money gold);
  void assign_key(Key key);
  void assign_potion(int potion);
  void assign_have_weapon(bool have_weapon);
  void assign_weapon_index(int weapon_index);
  void assign_have_scroll(bool have_scroll);
  void assign_scroll_index(int scroll_index);
  void assign_have_monster(bool have_monster);
  void assign_monster_index(int monster_index);

 private:

  int room_index;
  vector<int> exit_index;
  vector<string> exit_direction;
  vector<bool> exit_locked;
  vector<Money> gold;
  vector<int> key;
  vector<int> potion;
  vector<bool> have_weapon;
  vector<int> weapon_index;
  vector<bool> have_scroll;
  vector<int> scroll_index;
  vector<bool> have_monster;
  vector<int> monster_index;

};
```

This is the 'money' class declaration:

```
class Money{

public:

 Money() {
     value = 0;
 }

 Money(int amount) {
     value = amount;
 }

 friend int operator +(Money& initial_amount, int money_added);

private:

 int value;

};
```

This is the compiler error:

```
room.cc: In member function ‘void room::assign_exit_locked(bool)’:
room.cc:23:13: error: request for member ‘push_back’ in ‘exit_locked’, which 
is of non-class type ‘bool’
 exit_locked.push_back(exit_locked);
             ^
room.cc: In member function ‘void room::assign_gold(Money)’:
room.cc:29:6: error: ‘class Money’ has no member named ‘push_back’
 gold.push_back(gold);
      ^
room.cc: In member function ‘void room::assign_key(Key)’:
room.cc:35:5: error: ‘class Key’ has no member named ‘push_back’
 key.push_back(key);
     ^
room.cc: In member function ‘void room::assign_potion(int)’:
room.cc:41:8: error: request for member ‘push_back’ in ‘potion’, which is of 
 non-class type ‘int’
 potion.push_back(potion);
        ^
room.cc: In member function ‘void room::assign_have_weapon(bool)’:
room.cc:47:13: error: request for member ‘push_back’ in ‘have_weapon’, which 
is of non-class type ‘bool’
 have_weapon.push_back(have_weapon);
             ^
room.cc: In member function ‘void room::assign_weapon_index(int)’:
room.cc:53:14: error: request for member ‘push_back’ in ‘weapon_index’, 
which is of non-class type ‘int’
 weapon_index.push_back(weapon_index);
              ^
room.cc: In member function ‘void room::assign_have_scroll(bool)’:
room.cc:59:13: error: request for member ‘push_back’ in ‘have_scroll’, which 
is of non-class type ‘bool’
 have_scroll.push_back(have_scroll);
             ^
room.cc: In member function ‘void room::assign_scroll_index(int)’:
room.cc:65:14: error: request for member ‘push_back’ in ‘scroll_index’, 
which is of non-class type ‘int’
 scroll_index.push_back(scroll_index);
              ^
room.cc: In member function ‘void room::assign_have_monster(bool)’:
room.cc:71:14: error: request for member ‘push_back’ in ‘have_monster’, 
which is of non-class type ‘bool’
 have_monster.push_back(have_monster);
              ^
room.cc: In member function ‘void room::assign_monster_index(int)’:
room.cc:77:15: error: request for member ‘push_back’ in ‘monster_index’, 
which is of non-class type ‘int’
 monster_index.push_back(monster_index);
               ^
```

Comment: You've nanmed your class members the same thing as your paramters, so it's binding to the paramters.  If you must do this, use `this->vector.push_back`

Comment: @Donnie Comments aren't for answering.

Comment: @juanchopanza - it's such a trivial answer - I don;t see anything wrong with what Donnie did.  And he is correct.

Comment: @Tim What is wrong is that comments are not for answers. That is what answers are for. Triviality has nothing to do with it.

Comment: You are right, but I would expect the asker to then answer his/her own question and mark as correct.  It just seemed like chiding the person who posted a correct answer was not the best course of action.  This nitpicking is one of the reasons I stopped  using and participating ion SO for a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling calling `push_back` on the parameters rather than your class members. Either Use `this->` to refer to your members or make the names of the parameter and the member different (i.e. prefix your member variable with an underscore)